# Error importing some modules not happening when running interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

Basic data:

```
❯ python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

I have a Python project with some modules. I use `venv`, usually I start from scratch doing this:

```
❯ deactivate; rm -rf .venv && python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools --no-cache-dir # re-create venv
```

And installing my package with:

```
❯ pip install . --no-cache-dir
```

My setup.py file contains this:

```
...
# dependencies
    install_requires=[
        "Flask==1.1.2",
        "marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.22.3",
        "gunicorn==20.0.4"
    ],
...
```

All commands correctly execute.

But when I execute my Flask program (with or without `gunicorn`), I get this error:

```
...
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'marshmallow_sqlalchemy'
...
```

It doesn't make sense to me, because look at these commands.
1. pip doesn't lie:

```
❯ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
click                  7.1.2
Flask                  1.1.2
my-package             0.0.1
gunicorn               20.0.4
itsdangerous           1.1.0
Jinja2                 2.11.2
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
marshmallow            3.5.2
marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.22.3
pip                    20.1
setuptools             46.1.3
SQLAlchemy             1.3.16
Werkzeug               1.0.1
wheel                  0.34.2
```

And this is a total kill to me... this direct interpreter command doesn't give any error:

```
❯ python -c "from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema"
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Maybe try `python -m pip install <module>`. It's a classic solution, that works (sometimes).

Comment: Are you sure your pip gives you packages from venv? Can you try ```which pip```?

Comment: @Biarys 100% sure, look at the results of my command.

Comment: You run your flask application with a different Python, perhaps global.

Comment: @phd no, I checked, I activated venv. anyway it will fail much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments, it forced me to investigate a lot more! I found the explanation. Everything regarding `python` and `pip` binaries is OK:

```
❯ which python
{project_folder}/.venv/bin/python
❯ which pip
{project_folder}/.venv/bin/pip
```

But `flask` and `gunicorn` variables don't:

```
❯ which gunicorn
{HOME}/.pyenv/shims/gunicorn
❯ which flask
{HOME}/.pyenv/shims/flask
```

Here I need to explain that I use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to control my Python versions.

Said so, **I can correctly execute my app using explicitly `venv` binaries, `flask` and `gunicorn`**.

Anyway, I would like to understand why is `pyenv` not using proper `venv` binaries...